# Как решить проблему с удалением элементов из логического визуального дерева?

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте.

На форме есть StackPanel, добавленная в окно. В StackPanel из кода добавлются различные элекменты управления, в том числе и ComboBobox. При первом открытии окна все нормально при последующих выдаёт исключение

> Specified element is already the logical child of another element. disconnect it first.

Как в WPF C# удалить элемент из визуального дерева и исправить данную ошибку?

```
   StackPanel spi = new StackPanel();

   spi.Children.Add(cbc);
   spi.Children.Add(addArticleEditor);
   spi.Children.Add(delArticleEditor);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RemoveVisualChild(spi);
```

не помогает? Наверное, надо всё же хранить ссылку на StackPanel. Хотя непонятна ситуация - у Вас при последующем открытии зачем пересоздаётся StackPanel?

Может имеет смысл поменять архитектуру? Если хочется всё это делать кодом всё же, то может хранить ссылку на spi, и не пересозадвать стек панел, а делать аля

```
_spi.Children.Clear();
_spi.add ...
```

?

Comment: Нет так не срабатывает из кода проблему решил по другому. Но возникла та же самая проблема в методе base.OnPropertyChanged(e). Как в данном случае можно решить эту проблему?

protected override void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
            base.OnPropertyChanged(e);
}